# XPath Query based on Property and child elements

Tags: xml, xpath

Given the following(extremely simplified) XML:

```
<config>
  <Website name="DefaultSite">
    <Property key="Target" value="Apps" />
    <Property key="CertName" value="cert1" />
  </WebSite>
  <Website name="DefaultSite">
    <Property key="Target" value="Webs" />
    <Property key="CertName" value="cert2" />
  </WebSite>
  <Website name="RestAPI">
    <Property key="Target" value="Apps" />
    <Property key="CertName" value="cert1" />
  </WebSite>
</config>
```

I want to update the value for "CertName" in the second Website node where Target key is "Webs".  *Don't get me started on the structure, I don't have any control over it and it can't be changed.*  I have the following XPath string to get me most of the way to the correct Property value I want to change:
`/config/Website[@name='DefaultSite']/Property[@key='CertName']`

But, If I'm not mistaken, that would return both of the 'DefaultSite' elements from above.  How can I further filter to the desired element based on another child Property element?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.  If someone wants to confirm or provide an alternative, that would be great!

I found the following syntax for the filter that seems to provide the results I need:

```
/config/Website[@name='DefaultSite' and ./Property[@key='Target' and @value='Apps']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath expression should work. But it selects the first `website` node whereas you want the second. You can use the following expression :

```
/config/Website[@name='DefaultSite'][Property[@key='CertName']][Property[@key='Target' and @value='Webs']]
```

Or, as an alternative :

```
//Property[@key='CertName'][preceding-sibling::Property[@value="Webs"]]/..
```

Get the parent (`..`) of a `Property` element located anywhere (`//`) in the XML tree. This element fulfill 2 conditions : contains a specific attribute (key=) and  is preceded by a sibling `Property` element whith also a specific attribute (value=).

Output is the second `Website` element of the tree :

```
<Website name="DefaultSite">
<Property key="Target" value="Webs"/>
<Property key="CertName" value="cert2"/>
</Website>
```